# Replace All letters and more than 2 spaces in javascript string for empty character

Tags: javascript, regex, string

i need to replace in javascript string all letters and more than 2 spaces for "".
I have this:

```
order.Order.Telefonos = order.Order.Telefonos.replace(/[^A-Za-z]|[^\S\r\n]{2,}/, '');
```

But when order.Order.Telefonos have this:

```
"CASA: 1111111111      Varios:                Trabajo: 111111111"
```

return me this:

```
1111111111Varios:Trabajo:111111111
```

whats wrong on my regex?

Comment: You forgot the global modifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using negation: `[^...]`. Just use character class without negation, and use global modifier (`/..../g`) to replace all matches.

```
var s = "CASA: 1111111111      Varios:                Trabajo: 111111111";
s.replace(/[A-Za-z]|\s{2,}/g, '')
// => ": 1111111111:: 111111111"
```

Comment: Thats rigth, i forgott the global and set negation..Im new in Regex, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You did not copy the result verbatim, for your input it would be

```
'CASA 1111111111      Varios:                Trabajo: 111111111'
```

Then to your actual question: `[^A-Za-z]` is everything *but* letters, omit the `^`. Then do a global search with [`/…/g`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to find and replace every instance.